# Прочтение тела http-запроса в golang

Tags: golang, http, tcp

Я посылаю запрос на сервер и получаю ответ от него:

```
// Some code
queryUrl, err := url.Parse(someValidStringUrl)
resp, err := client.Get(queryUrl.String())
```

Проверим `err`:

```
if err != nil {
    log.Panic("Responce:", resp, "\nError:", err)
}
```

После этого я хочу получить тело моего ответа. Я делаю это следующим образом, но получаю пустой слайс байтов:

```
var bytes []byte
n, err := resp.Body.Read(bytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
log.Println(n, string(bytes))
```

Лог вывода:

> 2017/07/13 16:32:36 0

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673673/access-http-response-as-string-in-go) я нашёл другое решение:

```
// Some code
queryUrl, err := url.Parse(someValidStringUrl)
resp, err := client.Get(queryUrl.String())
if err != nil {
    log.Panic("Responce:", resp, "\nError:", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

if resp.StatusCode == 200 { // OK
    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(bodyBytes))
}
```

Пример вывода:

```html
<html lang='en'>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<title>Hello world</title>
</body>
</html>
```

В чём различия между этими примерами?
Почему мой вариант не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 возвращается потому, что у вас длина массива `bytes` равна 0. А функция `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)`, которую вы используете считывает в массив `p` до `len(p)` байт( в вашем случае 0) и возвращает количество прочитанных байт `(0 <= n <= len(p))`. Описание [Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). И, кстати, вызов  `defer resp.Body.Close()` тоже очень важно делать, чтобы не допустить утечки ресурсов. Подробнее [тут](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/index.html#close_http_resp_body).

Как бы должен был выглядеть ваш код:

```
import (
    "log"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    tr := &http.Transport{DisableKeepAlives: true}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    resp, err := client.Get("http://ident.me")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("Responce:", resp, "\nError:", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    bytes := make([]byte, 100)
    for {
        bytes = bytes[:cap(bytes)]
        n, err := resp.Body.Read(bytes)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
                log.Panic(err)
        }
        bytes = bytes[:n]
    }
    log.Println(string(bytes))
}
```